# Band-pass convolution/diff of Gaussians filter

Tags: image-processing

The [paper](http://www.karlsims.com/papers/siggraph91.html) I am reading calls for the use of a band-pass convolution that is performed using a difference of Gaussians filter. How does this image processing operation work?

Answer (score 1):

This probably refers to a difference of Gaussians filter. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians

In signal processing a filtering is described as the convolution of the original signal with a filter kernel. This is equivalent to transforming signal and filter to the frequency domain, multiply there and transform them back to the spatial domain afterward.